Movie where protagonists escape in a suicide rocket sled?
I can't remember the name of the movie that this scene is from.  Hopefully someone can help me out.
The two protagonists (one man and one woman) are being pursued in the desert.  They meet a man that has built a rocket car/sled on some rails extending far into the distance.  One character made some comment about it looking incredibly dangerous and the inventor replied along the lines of "Yeah, but what a way to go!"  Later when their pursuers arrive the protagonists narrowly escape in the rocket sled.  Unbeknownst to them there is a structure at the end track loaded full of explosives to which they are accelerating in the rocket sled.  I vaguely remember something like "Have a nice day!" written on the side.  The inventor had presumably built the track and rocket car as an elaborate device for his own suicide.  The protagonists somehow escape moments before a spectacular explosion.
The movie was in English and I'm pretty sure it was set in the United States.  I'm not sure when it came out.
What was the movie?

There was a similar scene in the latest Indiana Jones http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Rocket_sled

Pretty sure you're after Terminal Velocity from 1994 with Charlie Sheen and Nastassja Kinski.

Ditch Brodie is a maverick skydiving instructor. One day, a beautiful girl comes in, wanting to take her first jump. Up in the air, Ditch takes his eyes off her momentarily, then looks back to find out that she has fallen out, dying on impact. Ditch is suspicious that all is not as it seems, because he distinctly remembers hooking her static line on...

You can see them escaping on a rocket sled heading into a "Have a Nice Day" sign with a smiley face (built by an eccentric man in the desert) near the end of the trailer:




Wow.  That's a much younger Charlie Sheen!  Good memory, @Walt

Sadly [for the filmmakers, but luckily for you, I guess ;)] all I could remember of this film was the rocket-sled-smiley-face scene in the trailer...
